# WPF UI Layout for LOB Applications

Tags: wpf, user-interface, lob

I have been trying to find some resource on this topic for a while now but to no avail so what is the best way to construct a WPF UI for LOB (Line of Business) applications? specifically Customers, Orders, Products, etc.. I have seen many single window WPF application examples that don't need to be anything else but a single window and i've  looked at applications such as FamilyShow which looked promising until all I could see in the code was a big pile of user controls that faded in and out over the lifetime of the application and not something I could really use for lets say a 30-40 views in an application.

So what exactly am I asking? Well should I build a LOB application as a single WPF window with lets say a panel that has user controls dynamically loaded into it and then swap these out when lets say a navigation item is pressed or should I have multiple window forms that get shown or hidden when lets say a navigation item is pressed from a launching main form.

UI Design has never really been my strengh but i'm keen to learn so I would really appreciate your thoughts and offered experience in laying out your WPF LOB applications (Window+UC's or Windows) or could point me to any articles that cover WPF UI Layout design for LOB applications.

Thanks for reading...

Geoff.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what does LOB stand for? :)

Comment: @Meeh: http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/LOB

Take your pick. ;)

Comment: Line of Business? That's what we refer to it as in the banking industry...

Comment: @Randolpho - Hehe, yeah, that's where I went too. First google hit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is Microsoft's best practices for [composite client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707819.aspx).

This is probably the best thing to date as far as a framework and starting for business applications.  It is what it sounds like - a framework and basis for building a larger app out of smaller components, which happens a lot when creating LOB business apps.

Now, very specific to WPF, is the [prism framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx).  Which I believe shares some of the same concepts as the above composite application blocks (CAB).

Comment: I have looked at the Prism approach and did have that in mind which is steering me down the path of a main container that injects user controls.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, your UI look/feel depends heavily upon what you're trying to do. "Line of Business" (I assume you mean Line of Business by "LOB") is a very vague term that could mean dozens of different things. Your UI should be constructed to reflect which of those dozens of different things you're actually trying to do.

So I can only answer your question with another: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, Line Of Business applications... Well lets suppose I just have to design something with maintaining Customers, Orders and Products. I agree me using LOB was a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have been google a lot online to look for resources for WPF/Silverlight "LOB killer app". There was one very good demo(Bill Hollis) which you can find it [here](http://dnrtv.com/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0115)

WPF and MVVM is the the popular trend, I highly recommend to add it in your toolbox.
It's very powerful foundation for your application framework.  I think Microsoft nails databinding for WPF.  It's the very main core of the WPF technology to enable (developer & designer) co-exist.  It's very high learning curve, but worth the journey.
Happy coding.